How to remove and replace the squirrel cage on an inducer blower 510-312-273?
I have a Weil McLain gas furnace. The inducer blower squirrel cage has stripped off the motor. What's left of the squirrel cage centre is still attached to the motor shaft.
I'm finding it difficult to source the exact inducer motor assembly to fit onto the furnace. My question is, is it possible to open the section of the inducer blower that houses the squirrel cage and simply replace the cage.
Weil Mclain Part number 510-312-273 FASCO 702110410


On the squirrel cage blowers I have used, the side hole was too small allow the fan blade to come out. One side of the exit port could unscrew, and by removing the panel one could get the blade and motor out.
You'll have to get the whole metal blower box out of the furnace to get access to the exit port. Then remove the access panel and remove the blade and motor.
